# Where are the operators between nullable values and values defined (equality, greater than etc.)?

Tags: c#

If I have this code (I ran it in Linqpad):

```
decimal? x = null;
(x < 1).Dump();
```

where is the LessThan operator defined between the nullable decimal and decimal?.

It's not in decimal? and it's not in the decimal class.

I basically want to create linq expressions that invoke the operator.

Or is this code created on the fly by the compiler, i.e. it uses the default decimal operator and then it adds some additional statements to check whether the nullable value has actually a value?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Good idea, I've been blind. Yes, the answer is that the compiler compares the default value for the decimal type, and then it adds some code to determine the result of the operation by looking at whether the nullable types had values (in case the equality was true). So, there are no equality operators. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a so-called *lifted operator*, i.e. an operator defined on non-nullable type that compiler applies to nullable form of the same type.

> For the relational operators
>
> ```
>   <  >  <=  >=
> ```
>
> a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is `bool`. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single `?` modifier to each operand type. The lifted operator produces the value `false` if one or both operands are `null`. Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying operator to produce the `bool` result.

The details of the implementation are in section N.3.7 of the C# Language Specification.